# How can I save my github informations on git config file?

Tags: git, github

I just switch my OS to Linux and I'm having problems about git config file:
It's not saving my personal information, and every time, I must generate a token to commit changes.
There is a way to save these information without create a new token for each commit??
(I don't want to create a "no expiration token")

I tried to configure the file but actually, not works

Comment: A GitHub token *is* a password (it's just a specialized *kind* of password). Never save passwords in clear-text files, including Git configuration files, if at all possible. Consider using a *credential manager* that saves the token in some sort of encrypted form.